# Run-time error '91' displays even when I declare the object and set the object

Tags: vba

I don't have a clue what is happening with my `Excel VBA` code. I clearly declare `Levels` as object then set `Levels` as shown below. I Dim `Levels` after option explicit (module level) then set `Levels` within the subroutine itself. The strange thing is that the code was running perfectly fine until I added a few lines of code that had nothing to do with `Levels` at all. The code has been working for months and the code was duplicated and runs perfectly fine on another computer(without the newly added lines). But, even after setting `Levels` as an object as shown below, a Run-time `'91': Object variable not set` message is displayed. I tried using a brand new variable name but it gives me the same error, it just wont recognize that object that performs that task anymore.

```
Dim Levels As Object

Set Levels = IE.DOCUMENT.Body.GETElementsByTagName("div")
```

Comment: Add the lines that broke your code

Comment: Are you sure `IE.DOCUMENT.Body.GETElementsByTagName("div")` returns something?

Comment: and IE is something as IE.Document...

Comment: Try debugging it by adding multiple lines `Set Levels = IE`, then `Set Levels = IE.DOCUMENT`, then `Set Levels = IE.DOCUMENT.Body` - and see which line fails - that will tell you which one isn't an object but is actually `Nothing`.  (e.g. if `Set Levels = IE.DOCUMENT` works, but `Set Levels = IE.DOCUMENT.Body` fails then you know that `IE.DOCUMENT` was probably `Nothing`)

Comment: Thanks. the "IE" was in fact what was causing the problem. Thanks much